# How can I refresh and show/hide buttons in Buttons Container in Modal Dialog in Oracle APEX based on an Item Value?

Tags: oracle-apex

In Oracle APEX 22.1 (Oracle Database EE 21c) I have a Modal Dialog Box which has a button container with several buttons. These buttons are being shown or not, based on a item in dialog box variable that is 0 or 1.

When I press the button "UnDelete", a Dynamic Action of PL/SQL execution type is fired, change the value of a field in the database and then two another Refresh True Actions follow. The PL/SQL execution type changes the value of the field in the database of a table successfully and the first dynamic Action refreshes a Classic Report Region on the Modal Dialog Box showing the new correct value of the field.

The second Refresh True Action tries to Refresh the Button Container Region of the Modal Dialog Box in order to hide the button "UnDelete" and show the rest buttons, which all are Server Condition based on this variable value. The Refresh does not take place(maybe the Button Container Region does not support the Refresh Event or does not propagate it to its Buttons)?

How can I achieve this effect?

Thanks In Advance!

I tried the Refresh Action for the Button Container Region of the Modal Dialog Box,but the buttons are not shown/hide accordingly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Refresh" is not relevant for a button container. The "refresh" action in apex does an ajax call to refresh the content of a report - it just re-renders a part of the DOM containing data. Currently only the data rendered by a component can be refreshed using partial page refresh. A button can never "refreshed", it is rendered in the page rendering process and from then on it lives in the DOM for the lifespan of the page.

A server side condition is evaluated at page rendering time. If a server side condition yields false at page rendering time, the component is not included in the dom. So, they cannot be shown using a dynamic action afterwards (because they're not in the dom) and they cannot be re-evaluated using a dynamic action (because the dynamic action can only manipulate the dom and that condition was evaluated before the dom was rendered).

The solution to you problem is to use show/hide actions in a dynamic action for each of the individual buttons for the reasons explained above.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and in-depth response. I have limited JS knowledge thus the stuck.

Indeed, the issue was solved with  the help of anothet person. Solution was to put a JS code at both Clock Actions of the button with calls to $v('BUTTON_STATIC_ID').Show/Hide respectively. 

That is not enough though. Corresponding JS Code needs too be put on the Page Load Event to appropriately display or not the button at the Initial state.

Finally, the Server Conditions were removed completely in order for the buttons to exist in the DOM in able to "respond" accordingly.